# std::async fails for std::atomic_ref::wait?

Tags: c++, c++20

`std::async` works for own type and other std types like `thread`, why does it fail here for `std::atomic_ref` ?

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

struct Dummy
{
  Dummy() : value(0) {}
  void add(int i) { value +=i;}
  int value;
};

void func(){}

int main()
{
  // Dummy::add
  Dummy foo;
  auto f = std::async(&Dummy::add, &foo, 77);
  f.get();
  std::cout << foo.value << "\n";
  
  // std::thread::join
  std::thread t(func);
  auto f2 = std::async(&std::thread::join, &t);
  
  // std::atomic_ref::wait
  size_t a = 0;
  std::atomic_ref<size_t> atom(a);
  atom.wait(1); // OK
  auto f1 = std::async(&std::atomic_ref<size_t>::wait, &atom, 1); // error
}
```

[run](https://godbolt.org/z/f38bYe9Y3)

```
<source>:29:23: error: no matching function for call to 'async(void (std::__atomic_ref<long unsigned int, true, false>::*)(long unsigned int, std::memory_order) const noexcept, std::atomic_ref<long unsigned int>*, int)'
```

Comment: [std::atomic_ref::wait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref/wait) has a 2nd parameter (although it has a default value). If you add  such a parameter to `Dummy::add` you'll see the same issue. See the answer below for a solution.

Comment: Kind of a moot point – `atomic_ref::wait` and `thread::join` are not [designated addressable functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction), so using either of those in this context is UB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function pointers (including member function pointers) don't support default arguments, they are silently ignored.

[`std::atomic_ref::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref/wait) has a second parameter with a default argument: `std::memory_order order = std::memory_order::seq_cst`, and when calling through a member-pointer, it needs to be specified manually:

```
auto f1 = std::async(&std::atomic_ref<size_t>::wait, &atom, 1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Although I don't see what difference it makes to call `f` or `*(&f)` : signature and defaults are all known at compile-time, the compiler can add "`,std::memory_order::seq_cst)`" based on the signature (like it does when `f` is called) ..

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 Yep, looks like a slight defect in the language to me too. Don't see why it couldn't work.